Locally conformally flat
Is there any example of a locally conformally flat manifold that is neither a space form nor a product of space forms?

I don't think that products of space forms are locally conformally flat, except for products of flat space forms.

These aren't the only conformally flat products of space forms (the word "locally" is usually omitted). Any Fuchsian group acting on the hyperbolic $n$-space gives at infinity a conformally flat manifold diffeomorphic to $S^k\times M$ where $M$ is a hyperbolic $(n-k-1)$ manifold. By the way, one can take quotients of this by free finite group actions of hyperbolic isometries, e.g. any closed $3$-manifold modeled on $H^2\times \mathbb R$ is conformally flat.

The connected sum of two locally conformally flat manifolds can be equipped with a metrics which is locally conformally flat.  To see this, recall that the product metric on $\mathbb{R} \times S^{n-1}$ is (globally) conformal to the flat metric on $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$.
Metrics constructed this way are genuinely different from space forms or products of space forms (one of sectional curvature $+1$ and one of sectional curvature $-1$; or one which is one-dimensional and one which is not).  For example, in dimension four any closed spaceform has nonnegative Euler characteristic.  The connected sum $(S^1 \times S^3) \# (S^1 \times S^3)$ has negative Euler characteristic, and so is not a space form.  The only compact space forms with negative Euler characteristic are (quotients of) $S^2 \times \Sigma_g^2$, where $\Sigma_g^2$ is a compact surface with genus $g \geq 2$.  But the fundamental group of $(S^1 \times S^3) \# (S^1 \times S^3)$ is the free product $\mathbb{Z} \ast \mathbb{Z}$, which is not the fundamental group of any $\Sigma_g^2$.

Thank you for the answer


Any open parallelizable $n$-manifold immerses into $\mathbb R^n$ (this is special case of by Hirsch-Smale h-principle), and hence is conformally flat.

There are many examples of conformally flat manifolds arising from Kleinian groups, see the survey by Kapovich, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0701370 and references there, and an older survey Foundations of Flat Conformal Structure by Matsumoto.

A fun $4$-dimensional construction: Kapovich proved that every closed smooth spin 4-manifold appears as a connected summand of a conformally flat manifold, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210013. A version of this is known in dimension $3$.

There are many examples of conformally flat manifolds in dimension 3, see the above survey by Kapovich for references. Notably, it is still unknown which $\widetilde{SL}_2(\mathbb R)$ Seifert $3$-manifolds are conformally flat.



Thank you for the answer
